# IBM Cloud API resource controller missing zone id

Tags: api, ibm-cloud

I'm working on application which will get DNS entries of each of my `CIS` instances. To get `CIS` DNS records I need to provide `CRN` and `ZoneID`, however from resource controller I'm able to get only resource `CRN`. How to get related `ZoneID`?

Comment: Could you add a code / output sample of what you are doing and asking for? What API are you using?

Comment: I want to use the `https://resource-controller.cloud.ibm.com/v2/resource_instances` endpoint to get a list of all my CIS resources. Then I want to get DNS records of each instance using Golang package `github.com/IBM/networking-go-sdk/dnsrecordsv1`. The issue is that the Golang package requires `CRN` and `ZoneID` parameters to get DNS details, but the resource endpoint doesn't provide `ZoneID` (only `CRN`)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a flow of

- obtain your instances by retrieving them from the resource list (resource controller)
- retrieve the zones from your CIS instance (https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/cis#list-zones)
- retrieve the DNS entries for your CIS zones